# Asking about Context Free Grammar

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd like to know on what Stack Exchange site I should post specific, or general, questions about Context Free Grammars. I can't decide between Stack Overflow (general computing) or MathOverflow.

Comment: Just to be you understand, Stack Overflow **is not** for general computing. It is for programming questions

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for asking here -- it's better than getting your question downvoted and closed! For questions on the Chomsky hierarchy of grammars, there's potentially a number of sites to consider:

- [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) is mainly for questions relating to its implementation in tools (such as ANTLR and yacc) or actual code.
- [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com) is **probably what you are looking for** -- [they cover programming language semantics and formal methods](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
- [Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com) is **only suitable for research-level questions** -- while I don't know exactly what you're going to ask, it's unlikely that it would be of such a level.

However, [Math Overflow](http://mathoverflow.net) **[is not suitable for these sorts of questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/416/should-theoretical-computer-science-se-and-mathoverflow-be-merged)**, nor would [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.net) be suitable.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Computer Science Stack Exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com)?

Unless it's a programming question of course, then it might fit better on SO itself.